# A list of Objects get corrupted by some aliasing

Tags: javascript, oop

In my code I have an Object named "ToDoItem",
And i have another Object named "ToDoList".
which should have an Array of 'ToDoItem' Objects.

EDIT - A changed to a run able code:

```js
function ToDoItem(Text, date, isDone = false)
{

 if (!(typeof(Text) == "string") || (Text.localeCompare("") == 0))
 {
  return undefined;

 }
 if(!(date instanceof Date))
  return("please enter A valid Date");
 
 date.setUTCMonth(date.getUTCMonth()-1)
 console.log(date.getUTCMonth());
 this.Text = Text;   //type of String
 this.date = date;   //type of Date
 this.isDone = isDone;  //type of boolean
 
 if(typeof this.postpone != "function") 
 {
  ToDoItem.prototype.toString = function()
  {
   if ( typeof(this) == "undefined")
   {
   alert("here");

    return;
   }
   return ("Task: "  + this.Text + ", Date:" + this.date + " , isDone: " + this.isDone);
  }
  
  ToDoItem.prototype.isOutOfDate = function(now)
  {
   if(now == undefined || !(now instanceof Date) )
     return "please enter Date";
    
   if(now < this.date)   
    return true;
   return false;
  }

  ToDoItem.prototype.postpone = function(days)
  {
   if(days == undefined || !(typeof(days) == "number"))
    return "please enter a number";
   if(days < 0)
    return "this is negative number"; 
   if(days >= 0)
   {
    var oldDay = this.date.getDate();
    this.date.setDate(oldDay + days);
   }
  } 
 }
}
 
 
 
 
 
function ToDoList()
{
 var List =new Array;
 this.List = List;
 if(typeof this.addItem != "function") 
 {
  ToDoList.prototype.constructor = ToDoList;
  ToDoList.prototype.toString = function()
  {
   var str = "";
   for(var i=0;i<List.length;i++)
    str += i+1 + ":" + List[i].toString() + "\n";    
   return str;
  }
  
  ToDoList.prototype.addItem = function(item)
  {
   if(item == undefined || (!(item instanceof ToDoItem)) )
    return "please enter object type of item";
   
   this.List[List.length] = item;
  }
  
  ToDoList.prototype.getForDate = function(date)
  {
   if(date == undefined || !(date instanceof Date))
    return "please enter Date";
   
   var arr = [];
   var capacity = 0;
   
   for(var i=0;i<List.length;i++)
    if( (List[i].date.getDate() == date.getDate()) && (List[i].date.getMonth() == date.getMonth()) && (List[i].date.getYear() == date.getYear()) )
     arr[capacity++] = List[i];
    
   
   return arr;
  }
  
  ToDoList.prototype.getOutOfDate = function() 
  {
   var arr = [];
   var capacity = 0;

   for(var i=0;i<List.length;i++)
    if( List[i].isOutOfDate(new Date()) == true)
     arr[capacity++] = item;
   return arr;
  }
  
  ToDoList.prototype.postpone = function(index, days)
  {
   if(index == undefined || days == undefined || typeof(index) != Number || typeof(days) != Number)
    return "enter Numbers";
   if(days < 0 || index < 0)
    return "enter valid numbers";  
   if(index >= this.List.length)
    return "enter valid index";   
   
   List[i].postpone(days);
  }
 }
}

function tester() 
{
 var d1 = new Date(2015, 1, 1);
 var d2 = new Date(2015, 12, 1);
 var d3 = new Date(2016, 10, 17);
 var d4 = new Date(2016, 2, 14);

 var t1 = new ToDoItem("clean the house", d1);
 var t2 = new ToDoItem("fix toilet", d2);
 var t3 = new ToDoItem("buy shampoo", d3);
 var t4 = new ToDoItem("call dad", d4);

 var l1 = new ToDoList();
 l1.addItem(t1);
 l1.addItem(t2);
 console.log(l1.toString());
 var l2 = new ToDoList();
 l2.addItem(t3);
 l2.addItem(t4);
 console.log(l2.toString());
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
 <script type = "text/javascript" src="ToDo.js"> 
 </script>

    <head>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <script>tester();</script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have added the entire relevant code. need to run it on browser console.

The problem is that when I generate two different 'ToDoList' objects and prints, I get on the second Object the data of the first one and so on.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I looked at your code, but some of it is missing from the question, in particular the code for `ToDoItem`. Could you use the Snippet feature to turn the code into a runnable example and include all the code needed to make it run? If you edit the question and use the `<>` button it will insert a runnable snippet into the question.

Comment: thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reviewed your code and found some problems :

- List instead of this.list
- == instead of ===
- typeof(val) instead of (typeof val). Typeof is an operator, not a function
- misplaced prototype

Please see the code hereafter

```js
'use strict';
function ToDoItem(Text, date, isDone = false) {

 if ((typeof Text !== "string") || (Text.length < 1)) {
  return undefined;
 }
 if(!(date instanceof Date))
  return("please enter A valid Date");

 date.setUTCMonth(date.getUTCMonth()-1)
 console.log(date.getUTCMonth());
 this.Text = Text;   //type of String
 this.date = date;   //type of Date
 this.isDone = isDone;  //type of boolean
}

ToDoItem.prototype.toString = function() {
 return ("Task: "  + this.Text + ", Date:" + this.date + " , isDone: " + this.isDone);
}

ToDoItem.prototype.isOutOfDate = function(now) {
 if(now === undefined || !(now instanceof Date) )
   return "please enter Date";

 if(now < this.date)
  return true;
 return false;
}

ToDoItem.prototype.postpone = function(days) {
 if((days === undefined) || ((typeof days) !== "number")) return "please enter a number";
 if(days < 0) return "this is negative number";
 if(days >= 0) {
  var oldDay = this.date.getDate();
  this.date.setDate(oldDay + days);
 }
}



function ToDoList() {
 this.List = [];
}

ToDoList.prototype.constructor = ToDoList;
ToDoList.prototype.toString = function() {
 var str = "";
 for(var i=0; i<this.List.length; i++)
  str += i+1 + ":" + this.List[i].toString() + "\n";
 return str;
}

ToDoList.prototype.addItem = function(item) {
 if((item === undefined) || !(item instanceof ToDoItem) )
  return "please enter object type of item";
 this.List.push(item);
}

ToDoList.prototype.getForDate = function(date) {
 if((date === undefined) || !(date instanceof Date))
  return "please enter Date";
 var arr = [];
 for(var i=0; i<this.List.length; i++)
  if( (this.List[i].date.getDate() === date.getDate()) && (this.List[i].date.getMonth() === date.getMonth()) && (this.List[i].date.getYear() === date.getYear()) )
   arr.push(this.List[i]);
 return arr;
}

ToDoList.prototype.getOutOfDate = function() {
 var arr = [];
 for(var i=0; i<this.List.length; i++)
  if (this.List[i].isOutOfDate(new Date()) === true)
   arr.push(this.List[i]);
 return arr;
}

ToDoList.prototype.postpone = function(index, days) {
 if(index === undefined || days === undefined || (typeof index) !== Number || (typeof days) !== Number)
  return "enter Numbers";
 if(days < 0 || index < 0)
  return "enter valid numbers";
 if(! this.List[index])
  return "enter valid index";

 this.List[index].postpone(days);
}

function tester() {
 var d1 = new Date(2015, 1, 1);
 var d2 = new Date(2015, 12, 1);
 var d3 = new Date(2016, 10, 17);
 var d4 = new Date(2016, 2, 14);

 var t1 = new ToDoItem("clean the house", d1);
 var t2 = new ToDoItem("fix toilet", d2);
 var t3 = new ToDoItem("buy shampoo", d3);
 var t4 = new ToDoItem("call dad", d4);

 var l1 = new ToDoList();
 l1.addItem(t1);
 l1.addItem(t2);
 console.log(l1.toString());
 var l2 = new ToDoList();
 l2.addItem(t3);
 l2.addItem(t4);
 console.log(l2.toString());
}

tester();
```

Answer (score 1):

1) Replace all `List` (closure var) with `this.List` (object-ptoperty)

2) Move all prototyped-methods out of constructor - [solution](https://jsfiddle.net/br3t/ba1gezg0/)

Answer (score 0):

i think the problem lay in using List value in all  ToDoList functions instead of this.List.

In your case, during creating first instance of class ToDoList you are declaring function that use scope value List.

All next objects uses the same implementation, so they use List from first instance.